# POCO vs POCO Proxy vs STE - Which is the closest match for the way we do things now?

Tags: entity-framework

As part of a code modernization initiative, I'm trying to figure out a way to use the Entity Framework to augment (and eventually replace) our home-grown ORM.  The ORM itself is a huge step up from the straight SQL calls that were the prior step, but now that the rest of the infrastructure has been pulled up, I'd like to start phasing it out.

To that end, I'm trying to figure out how to build classes via the Entity framework so that they behave similarly to the way the current ORM does.  Ideally, there won't be any code changes needed as classes are redesigned, and we'll gain features like lazy-loading and ease of generating/updating the classes to match the database.

The current ORM is effectively a very fancy wrapper for building SQL statements.  `Part p = new Part(12345);` will execute `select * from parts where partID = 12345`, then take the DataRow it gets back and use reflection to populate the fields on the object.  When it saves, it does pretty much the same thing - it takes all the fields and uses that to update a datarow, which it then writes back to the database.  Usually, it also locks the row in the database when we expect it to be edited.  Kindof kludgy, but it works.

I'm trying to figure out a way to use the Entity framework and templates to automatically generate our classes in a way that doesn't require a persistent data context.  The current method allows us to create objects wherever they're needed, pass them around as necessary, and know that when they get updated, the database will update to match that object.  I've looked at various things (as per the title), but I can't tell which method we could use so that the context is unnecessary outside of the object library.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

---

**Edit:**  I might be asking for too much, or trying to squeeze a square peg into a round hole.  Let me simplify what I'm looking for, by stripping it down to the bare minimum.

Is there any way to structure this so I can have a CRUD-type object which is valid outside of a `using (var context = new Context()) {}`, so that I can pass it to unrelated code?  I don't care if I need to put it back into a context to load/save it, so long as it works outside it.

And if this is impossible using EF, what is the correct design pattern for this scenario: One form opens another and passes in an Invoice.  The second form takes that Invoice, steps the user through entering a payment for it, and generates a new Payment object.  The first form takes that Payment object and does further processing to the Invoice based on it.  Then, everything gets committed to the database at once.

Comment: So every class has a constructor which uses some sort of dependency injection container to receive an ORM retrieval service so that constructors like `Part p = new Part(12345);` will work?

Comment: How do your objects populate/update their collections?

Comment: @DannyVarod, Not so complex.  The base class has a function which builds up the `select * from parts where partID = 12345` statement based on all the fields marked with an `[IsKey]` attribute - it grabs the column name from an attribute, and the current value of that field.  And the constructor sets that value before calling that function.  So it becomes: Set key fields from constructor parameters, turn key fields into SQL, turn SQL into a DataRow, populate object by pulling each field out of the datarow and setting it's value.

Comment: @GertArnold, See the last comment for population.  Updates just flip that around - it gets the datarow (fresh), updates all the values to match the current ones, then saves that datarow.  There's a library that goes with the database which handles the translation between a SQL statement and a datarow and back.

Comment: @Bobson You still didn't explain how it knows which data source (connection) to use to get its values. Any way, there seems to be a real issue of spaghetti code here - your model's class are not only persistence aware - they are as persistence coupled as two items stuck together with super-glue.

Comment: @DannyVarod, There's only one data source, and the connection string is initialized as a static variable on the class that actually does the talking to the database.  That class makes calls to the 3rd party library provided by the database manufacturer.  It's also 4 years out of date (or was, until earlier this year).  Incremental steps.

Answer (score 0):

Neither POCO, POCO with Proxy or STE match your architecture. The point of all these entity types is to make your entities persistence ignorant but your entities implement persistence. The closest to your model are old DataSets.

Central point of EF is context. If you want to keep your architecture every entity will have to handle its own context. That is EF anti-pattern. EF expects that you have context and use the context to get and persist entities - most of EF features are dependent on this pattern.

Comment: I edited the question to more reflect what the real end goal is, rather than dealing with the how.  Does that change anything?  Is the fundamental workflow entirely incompatible with EF?

Answer (score 0):

If you really wants lazy loading with EF, then certainly you will need to create EF DbContext/Object Context. I guess it will be not a big deal to convert you current classes into POCO classes by removing code that is irrelevant such as persistence logic. I encourage you to abstract your persistence layer through a service layer that do the job of manipulating EF contexts, for example, your form calls the service layer and the service layer creates instances of context and persist/retrive data.

Answer (score 0):

If you use POCOs and turn off the context's proxy generation (or if you detach them after prior to disposing of the context) then your entities will be valid outside the using context clause.

If your objects have collection properties that you need to be valid outside the using context clause, you will need to use include in your queries or fill with additional queries prior to leaving the using context clause.

Comment: I can then reattach them to a context later, in order to commit it to the database?

Comment: Yes. You can also copy the property's values yourself if you want more control over what is to be changed and not (especially for navigation properties).